# How to add image at the background of terminal in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: gnome-terminal

During customization I want to add an image as the terminal background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal, go to Edit - Profile Preferences and select Background tab. Choose Background Image and select a file.